# How does %d format specifier work?

Tags: c

```
 #include<stdio.h>
 main()
 {
     char x ;
     x = 'a' ;
     printf("%d",x);
 }
```

In this %d format specifier should read 4 bytes being an integer format specifier but x being an character is stored in 1 byte only. so the remaining 3 bytes should have garbage value and the output should be random.
But the output is always coming 97 which is the ASCII value of 'a'.
Can anyone tell how the format specifier works ?

Comment: I think it is because `char x` is promoted to a `DWORD` in the stack.

Comment: @Neijwiert: There's no "stack" in the C language.

Comment: @KerrekSB I'm talking about the compiled code underneath the `C` language. Which could explain this behaviour.

Comment: @Neijwiert: But the OP was asking about the C language, not about your code generator!

Comment: if you want to read 4 bytes char, you have to use wide char :      wchar_t x ;     x = L'a' ;     wprintf( L"%lc",x);

Comment: It would be interesting to have a look into what the C compiler translates this on the assembler level.

Answer (score 12):

Function arguments that don't match a declared parameter type of the function (i.e. because the function allows for variable arguments, like `printf`, or because no function prototype has been provided) undergo the *default argument promotions* (cf. C11 6.5.2.2), which turn a `char` value into a value of `int` or `unsigned int`. Therefore, passing `a` to `printf` matches the requirement for `%d`.

Comment: In standard C, if an `int` can represent all values of a `char`, the `char` value will be promoted to an `int`, otherwise it will be promoted to an `unsigned int`. So in most implementations it would be promoted to `int`, because the only case where an `int` cannot represent all the values of a `char` is when a `char` and an `int` are the same size (i.e. when `sizeof(int) == 1`) and `char` is unsigned. Such implementations are quite rare!

Comment: So I've heard, although I haven't encountered such a platform myself yet.

Comment: #include<stdio.h>
 main()
 {
     int x ;
     x = 1 ;
     printf("%lld",x);
 }   This gives the output 11821485165379585 which is random number .this is because %lld reads 8 bytes but int is of 4 bytes . same should be the case with my question

Comment: @KushagraSinghal: That's because that code has undefined behaviour, because you are violating printf's requirements. Unlike in your original code, which is fine.

Comment: okk i m still confused 
if char is automatically promoted to integer then why not integer is promoted to long long integer ??
please help me .

Comment: @KushagraSinghal: Because the language rules says so. I don't really have much more to say; C is a weird, complex language with a ton of warts like that. Look up the reference I cited for details.